# How to check if username exists without refreshing page using wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I want to check a text field in form that if username exists in database or not.i want it without refreshing page and i am using Wordpress.I know it is possible through ajax but i have tried ajax in Wordpress and any ajax code didn't run on it. Kindly provide any piece of code or any helpful link. Last time i have tried this but didn't work:

```
<?php
if(!empty($user_name)){ 

$usernamecheck = $wpdb->get_results("select id from wp_teacher_info where      user_name='$user_name'");
if(!empty($usernamecheck)){
echo'username not available';
}
else {

}
}?>

<label for="user_name" id="user_name">Username: </label>
<input type="text" name="user_name" id="user_name" required/>
<span id="user-result" ></span>


<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery("#user_name").keyup(function (e) { //user types username on   inputfiled

var user_name = jQuery(this).val(); //get the string typed by user
jQuery.post('teacher_form.php', {'user_name':user_name}, function(data) { 
jQuery("#user-result").html(data); //dump the data received from PHP page
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
if(!empty($_POST['user_name']){ 
  $user_name = $_POST['user_name'];
```

to be

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST['user_name']){ 
      $user_name = $_POST['user_name'];
      $usernamecheck = $wpdb->get_results("select id from wp_teacher_info where user_name='$user_name'");
      if(!empty($usernamecheck)){
         echo'username not available';
      }
      else {

      }
}
?>
```

but keyup event will call the ajax each keyup .. you can use  `**.blur()**`  instead of `**.keyup()**`

Comment: @Khan what the meaning of  its not working .. any errors? nothing happened? .. check teacher_form.php path

Comment: Nothing happened when i typed the username which exists in database. @Mohammed-Yousef